# Get start and end dates of selected view in kendo scheduler to filter events in database query

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-view

I am wanting to filter events in my kendo scheduler from local database, not remote. Kendo website has examples on how to filter events by date using remote data... but not really local.

My plan was only to pull in the current scheduler view's events (events that occur from the start date of the view, be it month or week, or day, to the end date of the view). However, in the scheduler navigate event, you can seemingly only get the start and end date of the view you were just on, not the one you just clicked on and switched to...

I am wondering if there is a way to get the 'future' view start and end dates of the kendo scheduler, then query my database in a remote function, pull the events after start date and before end date, reset my array of kendo events to these new ones and resync my scheduler?

This is largely because I am dealing with thousands and thousands of events that I want the user to be able to see in the past or present as far back as they need to, but if they can only see a max of a month of events at a time (or week or day) there will never be very many events returned at one time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check the Kendo UI Documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/filtering/server-filtering

and more specifically this code section:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/blob/master/scheduler-server-filtering/KendoUI_Scheduler_Server_Filtering/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L46

Comment: Hmm... well my issue is that I am not using remote data. I query a database in an apex controller to get events, then keep them locally. So the parameter map is not utilized as that is executed when using remote data. So I guess I am just trying to find where I can access the current view's start and end date

Comment: Yep, this is an important clarification.
In that case, you can use either dataBound or navigate events, where the latter is much more useful. Here some demos: 1. http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/ONIMO (get view range in navigate/dataBound events) 2. http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/OgIFE (bind widget on navigate).
If the comment helps, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you. I found the navigate is not entirely useful for my purposes. Unfortunately, they wired up the navigate to only give you access to the start and end dates of the view you WERE in, not the one you are going to when you click a navigation button :(. But the dataBound and dataBinding events both give you access to the view you are going to, which is what I am needing.